# Ng-hide and last:child CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have;

```
<div class="exampleDiv">
    <element1></element1>
    <element2></element2>
    <element3></element3>
</div>
```

then some CSS using the last:child selector (only margin-right:0 FYI). However I use a conditional ng-hide on elements 1-3 and so if element3 is hidden, the last:child CSS is not moved to element2 as technically it is rendered in the DOM then hidden.

So I was wondering is there a way to use ng-hide and have something like a 'last-visible-element' selector. So that as ng-hide does its work, the last element the user can see has this CSS applied to it?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: are these elements inside ng-repeat?

Comment: @Abhidev Nope just regular elements (buttons to be precise)

Comment: can you mention the conditional ng-hide as well?

Comment: would this help https://www.tutorialsplane.com/angularjs-remove-html-element-from-dom/ ?  example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmvKdV

Answer (score 1):

is [remove()](https://www.tutorialsplane.com/angularjs-remove-html-element-from-dom/) what you look for since it does remove element from the dom tree:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
 myApp.controller("myController", function($scope) {
 $scope.removeElement = function() {   
  var elmn = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.test :last-child' ) );
     elmn.remove();
 };
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.test div {
  border: solid;
  min-width: 5em;
}

.test :last-child {
  color: red;
}
.test :last-child:before {
 content:"actual last-child ";
 color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <p>each time you click, last element is removed</p>
  <div ng-controller="myController" class="test">
    <input type="button" value="Remove Div " ng-click="removeElement()">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>last-child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KmvKdV

Answer (score 0):

you may try adding `dynamic` class based on `some condition`, something like :-

`css / style`

```
.show {
    display: inline;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

`script`

```
<div class="exampleDiv">
   <element1 ng-class="{'show' : item.isVisible == true, 'hide' : item.isVisible == false}"></element1>
   <element2 ng-class="{'show' : item.isVisible == true, 'hide' : item.isVisible == false}"></element2>
   <element3 ng-class="{'show' : item.isVisible == true, 'hide' : item.isVisible == false}"></element3>
</div>
```